# What is -D__USE_FIXED_PROTOTYPES__ in GCC used for?

Tags: c, unix, gcc, makefile

In the book [Practical C Programming](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565923065.do), *Chapter 7 Programming Process*, there is a makefile:

```
File: calc1/makefile.gcc
#-----------------------------------------------#
#   Makefile for unix systems       #
#    using a GNU C compiler         #
#-----------------------------------------------#
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -D__USE_FIXED_PROTOTYPES__ -ansi
#
# Compiler flags:
#   -g  -- Enable debugging
#   -Wall   -- Turn on all warnings (not used since it gives away
#           the bug in this program)
#   -D__USE_FIXED_PROTOTYPES__
#       -- Force the compiler to use the correct headers
#   -ansi   -- Don't use GNU extensions.  Stick to ANSI C.

calc1: calc1.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o calc1 calc1.c

clean:
    rm -f calc1
```

What are "correct headers"? Why there is no space between option parameters **-D** and **__USE_FIXED_PROTOTYPES__**?

In the [GCC mirror](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libobjc/memory.c), there is:

```
/* __USE_FIXED_PROTOTYPES__ used to be required to get prototypes for
   malloc, free, etc. on some platforms.  It is unclear if we still
   need it, but it can't hurt.  */
#define __USE_FIXED_PROTOTYPES__
```

There is explanation from [Re: Is `__USE_FIXED_PROTOTYPES__` really necessary?](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/1997-10/msg00227.html).

But I do not get the points.

This PRACC book was published in 1997, a bit old but still very useful. The Makefile is bit outdated, and I wonder whether the .gcc extension is needed anymore.

Neither of these is mentioned in [Errata for Practical C Programming](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9781565923065).

Comment: The space between `-D` and `__USE_FIXED_PROTOTYPES__` is optional.  Note that the `-ansi` flag is obsolescent in the sense that you should now use one of `-std=c90` (which is what `-ansi` means, more or less), or `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` (preferably the latter), or one of the GNU variants (such as `-std=gnu11` — which is the default in GCC 7 (and 6, and 5 IIRC, but not the default in earlier versions).

Comment: Using a 1997 programming book in 2017, error 2018, is like using a construction book from 1307.

Comment: The `.gcc` suffix to `makefile` was probably used to allow different makefiles to be written for different compilers.  If you plan to use GCC, then the suffix really isn't needed.  The only harm it does is that you have to type `make -f makefile.gcc` rather than just `make` — at least until you type `ln -s makefile.gcc makefile` (or `mv makefile.gcc makefile`).  The `__USE_FIXED_PROTOTYPES__` stuff seems to have been necessary 20 years ago; it hasn't been necessary for most of this millennium, though.  Remove it from the makefile; it is historical material that is now irrelevant.

Comment: To be sure can you clarified what edition of this book do you use ? Is it the 3rd or not ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of this is wrong. I don't know what's practical in forcing the compiler to stick to  the deprecated 1989 standards revision in **2018**, 7th year after the publication year of the latest revision of 2011.

The necessity of `__USE_FIXED_PROTOTYPES__` seems to have been discussed [in 1997](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/1997-10/msg00227.html). It is to make the code work on platforms where the header files **predate the 1989 standard**. You ain't gonna need it. Back then you could have a program that did the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    void *p = malloc(42.0);
}
```

And the program would have undefined behaviour because the `<stdlib.h>` wouldn't contain a prototype, and the argument is of wrong type.

Now GCC doesn't work like that. Ever since C99, if a prototype is missing, GCC will complain loudly. It will also complain about wrong argument types, etc:

```
// #include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    void *p = malloc(42.0);
}
```

When compiled:

```
% gcc test.c 
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:2:15: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘malloc’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     void *p = malloc(42.0);
               ^~~~~~
test.c:2:15: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
test.c:2:15: note: include ‘<stdlib.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘malloc’
```

With `-pedantic-errors` the implicit function declaration becomes an error that causes the compilation to fail (as it should).

I am not even sure if this actually has any effect right now. Presumably this was to fix the declarations so that whenever you'd include `<stdlib.h>` it would also mean that for example `malloc` would have a correct prototype, not, say, implicit function declaration. It might have been relevant 20 years ago when compiling for systems 15 years old. Now it is relevant when compiling for systems 35 years old.

If this is the kind of the practical advice that the book gives, my practical advice is to use it as a fuel for a combustion process. It is probably the most useful thing you can do with it.

Instead of all these flags, if you value standard-conformity, use

```
-Wall -std=c11 -pedantic-errors
```

Without `-pedantic-errors`, even `-std=c11 -Wall` will allow some GCC specific extensions to slip through.

Comment: Your 'with no includes' comment about code that contains an include is a bit confusing, perhaps.  And you used to need to write `extern char *malloc();` to get the pre-standard return type right — it wasn't `void *` before C90, and there wasn't a standard header that declared it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ah that was just a left-over sentence, who has time to proofread in 2018.